# GORM is not persisting the changes of an object

Tags: grails, sql-update, grails-orm

I have a service class that is responsible for managing Project entity (simple things for now).

```
@Transactional
class ProjectService {

    UserService userService

    ...

    @Publisher(ProjectEvent.PROJECT_UPDATED)
    Project updateById(Long id, ProjectCommand command, Long updatedById) {
        User updatedBy = userService.getById(updatedById)
        Project project = getByIdAndOwner(id, updatedBy)

        if (!updatedBy) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("user was not found", User)
        }

        if (!project) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("project was not found", Project)
        }

        project.title = command.title
        project.background = command.background
        project.problemStatement = command.problemStatement
        project.updatedBy = updatedBy
        project.lastUpdated = new Date()
        project.save()
    }

    @Publisher(ProjectEvent.PROJECT_DELETED)
    Project deleteById(Long id, Long deletedById) {

        User deletedBy = userService.getById(deletedById)
        Project project = getByIdAndOwner(id, deletedBy)

        if (!project) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("project was not found", Project)
        }

        project.deletedAt = new Date()
        project.deletedBy = deletedBy
        project.save()

        project

    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except the deletion.
As you can see I am trying to implement soft deletion of an object. In simple words, it's an update, as any other update.

The update method works fine, whenever any data actually changes. As expected, an update query is executed (as expected).

However, when I an trying to use `deleteById`, the object returned from this method has `deletedAt` and `deletedBy` set properly, but no update query is executed, and eventually the record, of course, not updated in DB.

`project.save(flush: true)` does not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Something worth mentioning is the structure of my `Project` class. It extends `AuditableEntity` where:

```
abstract class AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    Date dateCreated
    User createdBy
    Date lastUpdated
    User updatedBy
    Date deletedAt
    User deletedBy

    static constraints = {
        createdBy nullable: true
        updatedBy nullable: true
        deletedBy nullable: true
        dateCreated nullable: true
        lastUpdated nullable: true
        deletedAt nullable: true
    }
}
```

All the rest of the Project properties are defined in the Project class itself.

**UPDATE**
For some reason, in `deleteById` method, just before the save call, `project.isDirty()` returns `false`. Why?

**UPDATE #2**
Another interesting thing, if I add the definition of these two properties in Project class itself (overriding them), everything starts working... 
That is unexpected. Why is it happening?

Comment: Apparently dirty checking is not working for superclass field changes because they are private by default. Try making both `deletedAt` and `deletedBy` public or protected and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same issue in my project.

I couldn't figure out why, but it seems that you have to tell the system to use Hibernate's way of dirty checking an object, that is, see if it's changed.

hibernate:
hibernateDirtyChecking: true

adding this helped me solve the issue.
Although Im still trying to figure out why GORM's dirty checking does not work.